# Android OでChrome無効設定時にwebviewを含むactivityで落ちる

Tags: android

Chrome無効設定時にwebviewを含むactivityで落ちる状況です。
改善方法がなく困っております。

1. 設定->設定->アプリと通知からChromeを無効にする
2. webviewを含むアプリを起動し、webviewのあるactivityまで遷移する

上記手順２でアプリが強制終了します。
事象はAndroid 6.0 / 7.0では起きておらず、Android O(APIレベル26 / 8.0.0)で起きている
その他は不明

該当コードは下記の通りです

```
public class TestWebActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testweb);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

エラーログは下記の通り

> 12-28 16:41:42.146 31047-31047/xxxxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: xxxxxxxxx, PID: 31047
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.TestWebActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)

Error inflating class android.webkit.WebViewについてはAndroid5でのバグの話はありますが、Android Oでの事象が見つかりませんでした。

何かご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらお知らせいただけると幸いです。

Comment: Android 8.0のNexsu 6Pのみで起きている可能性が高い。
Yahoo、価格コム、iLunascapeなどwebviewを使っているであろうアプリで同様の現象が起きる。

Comment: ところで開発者オプションからWebviewに使用するアプリの選択は利用可能ですか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/106831

Answer (score 1):

該当の機種がAndroid8βから8.0.0にアップデートしたものだっただめ起きていたようです。
同様の状態の機種が２台あり、１台は8.1にアップデートでこの事象は起こりませんでした。
もう１台は8.0.0のままで端末のリセットをかけると同様の事象は起こらなくなりました。

ここからは憶測ですが、Android8βから8.0.0にアップデートした際にchrome等のパッケージがβで利用されていたものが残っていたのではないかと推測しています。